# elements of nested sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking about elements of the power set, and I know that for a power set $P=\{\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ that $\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}$ are all elements of $P$. However, if you have another set containing sets, such as $A=\{1, 2, \{3, 4\}\}$: is 3 an element of $A$?

Comment: 3 is an element of an element of A but not an element of A.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.$\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$